# 'NSDictionary?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `plist` file, `dictionary` type, and trying to read its items:

[image]

Code to loop through the `NSDictionary`:

```
let inputFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("frames", ofType: "plist")

let inputDataDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: inputFile!)
for inputItem in inputDataDictionary {
    println(inputItem)
}
```

But it says:

```
'NSDictionary?' does not have a member named 'Generator'
```

[image]

Comment: `inputDataDictionary` is an optional. Either unwrap via `!` or use an `if let`...

Comment: @Alladinian thanks, worked. Post it as a new answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `inputDataDictionary` is an optional. You 'll have to either unwrap it via `!` or check the value with an `if let` before the enumeration. Also note that the recommended way of iterating a dictionary is via a tuple. Something like this:

```
if let dict = inputDataDictionary {
    for (key, value) in dict {
        println("\(key), \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative if you don’t need code to handle when the value is `nil` is to use the nil-coalescing operator with the for: `for (k, v) in inputDataDictionary ?? [:] { println("\(k), \(v)") }`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Sure. He could also use the `??` in the declaration as well: `let inputDataDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: inputFile!) ?? [:]` in order to ensure a non-optional instance, although in both cases he would miss any errors (by providing a wrong file path for example).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for inputItem in inputDataDictionary.allKeys {
    println(inputItem)
}
```

Or you can also use:

```
for (key, object) in inputDataDictionary {
    println(key)
    println(object)
}
```

Comment: I agree with Danny, using for (key, object) should work!

Comment: That is strange, I just ran a test on a playground using, and everything runs ok: 

`let inputDataDictionary = NSDictionary(object: NSObject(), forKey: "test");
for (key, object) in inputDataDictionary {
    println(key);
    println(object);
}`

Maybe try a clean build?